# Can 10k+ users and mods see deleted questions in the question list?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, deleted-questions

I am thinking of the question list pages, for example, default pages of the sites (i.e. without any tricky things, for example, searching for tags, etc).

I am thinking of the question *list*, and *not* when they click to the link of an individual question, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, deleted questions are not shown in lists.

Moderators can search for deleted questions or answers using the `deleted:1` operator, however. 10k users can also use that operator, but it only returns their own deleted questions or answers.